# Div disapears when hovering over autocomplete input

Tags: jquery, css

I have a login box with id and a password input. It opens when hovering over a div. The problem is that when I mouseover the autocomplete field the div closes.

```css
.header-compte:hover .header-compte__content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-compte__content">
  <div class="header-compte__content__form">
    <form id="navbar-login-form" class="px-5 py-3" method="POST" action="{{ route('shop.login') }}" novalidate>
      @csrf
      <div class="form-group form-group-mm">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-mm @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-group-mm">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-mm @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Mot de passe" required autocomplete="current-password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-check w-100 text-left mb-4">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input form-check-input-mm" name="remember" {{ old( 'remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
        <label class="form-check-label form-check-label-mm" for="exampleCheck1">Rester connecté</label>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary-mm">Connexion</button>
      </div>
      <a class="btn btn-link btn-link-mm" href="" rel="nofollow">{{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}</a> 
      @if (Route::has('password.request'))
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a class="btn btn-link" href="" rel="nofollow">{{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}</a>
        </div>
      @endif
    </form>
    <div class="header-compte__content__new">
      <p class="mb-3">Nouveau client ?</p>
      <a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary-mm" rel="nofollow">Créer un compte</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.header-compte:focus` instead of hover